# Parameter File in Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, rodbc, sqldf

I am using a database in Shiny App. I have created a long list of choose button to select multiple option (since I have to select more than one option). Problem is, the main screen (for user ui) is becoming very large. I have more than 20 options in couple drop down.

Can't I select more than one option in select drop down list? Since it will reduce the overall size of main user ui screen.

Note- I wanted to post the image of what I have created, but don't know how to paste the real image. I tried but it was taking the link.

Thanks  Jdharrison for your response! Actually I don't want to add them horizontal. My question is is it possible to select more than one option in drop-down list? So far I think, we can select only one option from drop-down.

Comment: Look at accordions in bootstrap 2 http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse. You can group your options in accordions. The `shinyBS` package will allow you to use them.

Comment: Perhaps you can upload images now. If you still cannot, try to include a link after you upload to imgur.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By drop down list, you mean `selectInput()`? If that is the case, you can certainly do multiple choices using `selectInput(..., multiple = TRUE)`.

Comment: Yithui - Thanks a lot for your help. This worked perfectly the way I was looking for. Thanks again. Regards,

Comment: @Piyush Marking the answer as "Accepted" is the correct way of saying "thanks" on StackOverflow :)

Comment: @Piyush if an answer was helpful you can also press the up arrow for the answer.